# VS 2017 Crystal Reports table not found error when setting Parameters

Tags: crystal-reports, visual-studio-2017

When we set a Parameter using .`SetParameterValue()`, the report will not run and throws an exception: Table not found.

> CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.DataSourceException: Error in
>   File 31 77792_72788_{CACA007E-62DB-4EED-804A-915E3ED04293}.rpt: The
>   table could not be found. --->
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException:

```
 ReportDocument r = new ReportDocument();
 r.Load("31.rpt");
 SetReportConnection(r);
 // This line removed, and it works fine with the default parameters...  
 r.SetParameterValue("BOOKFROM", 201701);
 r.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, "test.pdf");
```

Comment: Okay, looks like this is a problem with the .rpt file.   A very basic report actually works just fine.

Comment: So the report runs just fine after initially converting it from FoxPro to SQL Server data source.   But then, attempting to set the Parameter Value throws this error.    I've stripped the offending report down to almost nothing, and still get the error.

Comment: 'The table could not be found. ' Maybe it's still expecting data source from FoxPro ? ( can you debug and see where it crashes) ?